# Why does my <th> query selector return null?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors, devtools

elements that I select have these properties in the DOM when I inspect them however, my selectors still return null in the console. Why is this?

https://www.espn.com/nfl/player/stats/_/id/2580/drew-brees

```js
console.log("by textContent:", document.querySelector('th[textContent=GP]'));

console.log("by title:", document.querySelector('th[title="Games Played]'));
```

```html
<table>
<thead class="Table__header-group Table__THEAD">
  <tr class="Table__sub-header Table__TR Table__even">
    <th title="Games Played" class="Table__TH">GP</th>
    <th title="Completions" class="Table__TH">CMP</th>
    <th title="Passing Attempts" class="Table__TH">ATT</th>
    <th title="Completion Percentage" class="Table__TH">CMP%</th>
    <th title="Passing Yards" class="Table__TH">YDS</th>
    <th title="Yards Per Pass Attempt" class="Table__TH">AVG</th>
    <th title="Passing Touchdowns" class="Table__TH">TD</th>
    <th title="Interceptions" class="Table__TH">INT</th>
    <th title="Longest Pass" class="Table__TH">LNG</th>
    <th title="Total Sacks" class="Table__TH">SACK</th>
    <th title="Passer Rating" class="Table__TH">RTG</th>
    <th title="Adjusted QBR" class="Table__TH">QBR</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot query by `textContent` since it is not an **attribute**

Comment: The closing `"` is missing.

Comment: Thank you both. It works now. I've left out the quotes around the value before but my guess is that since there's a space between Games Played, the quotation marks are needed. Also, I guess this is an instance in which it doesn't help to try and 'fit a square peg into a round hole.' @Phil